# buttons enabled based on multiple user conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, user-controls, conditional-statements

I have a user Control called DisabledControl. I need to create 1 if statement with these two conditions.

```
public static class DisabledControl
{
    public static void AdminOnly(this Control control)
    {
        control.Enabled = User.IsInRole(new string[] { "Administrator" });
    }

    public static void OwnerOnly(this Control control, int ownerID)
    {
        control.Enabled = (User.ID == ownerID);
    }
}

//I need help with syntax: if User isinRole 'Adminstrator" && user is OwnerOnly, btnSave.Enabled=true. 
//I tried to use if user.id == OwnerOnly, it gives error.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `user.id == OwnerOnly` because `OwnerOnly` is a method that returns `void`. You would need `user.id == ownerID`, or change `OwnerOnly` to return a `boolean`.

In response to your comments, try something like this:

```
public static void SetEnabledForAdminOrOwner(this Control control, int ownerID)
{
    control.Enabled = User.IsInRole(new string[] { "Administrator" }) || User.ID == ownerID;
}
```

Comment: I need help either way, calling OwnerOnly and AdminOnly controls from another form in the formload().

Comment: @Gina I'm not sure what you're asking. You have written extension methods to toggle the `Enabled` property. You could just add another method to handle the case of Admin || Owner.

Comment: I can do them seperate like this: btnSave.AdminOnly(); and btnSaved.OwnerOnly((int)InvestigatorCase.CreatedBy(); but I need buttonSave.enabled=true, if user is both OwnerOnly && AdminOnly. Maybe a different way to show me?

Comment: Only an Admin and the owner who created the record can save and edit this record. That is why my OwnerOnly and AdminOnly controls.

Comment: wow Jon B. That works better than what I have. Thanks a bunch :)